# Virtual function

Tags: c++

```
class a
{
 virtual void foo(void) ;
};

class b : public  a
{
public:
 virtual void foo(void)
  {
  cout<< "class b";
  }
};

int main ( ) 
{
class a *b_ptr = new b ;
b_ptr->foo();
}
```

please guide me why the b_ptr->foo() will not call the foo() function of the class b?

Comment: The declaration of b_ptr in main should not be preceded by the word "class"

Comment: @Rachel I would add that it should not but it is not considered illegal, only useless in this case.

Comment: @Drahakar, it is still not idiomatic C++ and shouldn't be done. Similarly, an explicit void parameter is permitted but is C syntax and is not idiomatic C++, and, therefore, should be avoided.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan well, from what I can see, the explicit void parameter has no real use, but the declaration class a *b_ptr would be helpful if the class name a would be hidden by an other structure like a function name. You can find this example like that in The Annotated C++ page 167. I agree with you that it has no real value in this example, but still, I thought it was something good to know.

Answer (score 17):

As you've written the code, it won't compile due to access control violations.  Since `b_ptr` is actually of type `a *` and `a::foo` is private, the compiler won't allow that.

But make `a::foo` public and that will correctly call `b::foo`.

There is also the problem that you have not defined `a::foo` so your program won't link.  You need to either define it or make it pure virtual (i.e `virtual void foo(void) = 0;`).

Comment: +1 You might want to say access *specification* violations to distinguish this from what happens when you have a rogue pointer :P

Comment: @BillyONeal - I liked the gist of your recommendation although I decided to go with access *control* violation as that is closer to how the standard describes this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Because a:foo() is not public.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. Write `foo()` and not `foo(void)`... the latter is unnecessary and not idiomatic C++ (it is C-like syntax).
2. Don't write `class` in `a* b_ptr = new b;`, since a's type has already been declared.
3. You should return from a function that doesn't return void (add `return 0`).
4. Your code never frees `b_ptr`. It would be better to write `std::auto_ptr<a> b_ptr(new b);`.
5. The compile-time type (declared type) of `b_ptr` is `a*` while it's runtime type (instantiation/allocation type) is `b*`. The compiler (and the type system) only know about compile time types, and so checks for access privileges are performed based on compile-time type... hence `b_ptr->foo()` isn't allowed.
6. Either use a declared type of `b*` or make `a::foo` public to use it in the way you wish.

Comment: @GMan: How do you tell the difference between someone who wanted to `return 0` and so didn't write anything, and someone who forgot to think about returning a value at all?

Comment: @Bill: I dunno. They forgot a return in a function requiring a return?

Comment: @Gman: As you pointed out, `main` doesn't require a `return`. How do you tell the difference there?

Comment: @Bill: You don't. What's your point? We don't need to waste time walking down a primrose path like there's some deeper meaning here. Item 3 is misinformed, it doesn't mention anything about what I said. The correct point would be "You probably forgot to return 0, though you got lucky here because `main` implicitly returns 0". Mention the concern along with why it still worked.

Comment: @Gman: Ah, I see.  I thought you meant that because `main` implicitly returns 0 that item 3 didn't need to be there at all.  Never mind!

Answer (score -1):

Make that

```
class a
{
public:
    virtual void foo(void);
};
```

<strike>You can't override a private function.</strike> Though I'm not sure how you managed to call `b_ptr->foo()` anyways since `a::foo` is private.

Comment: This is not true. You certainly can override a private function - it's actually quite good practice.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Explain?

Comment: It's legal to override a private function; it's just private, so you can't call it (through the base class) by a non-friend. It's common practice to use mostly private virtual functions that are called only by the base class's member functions. I forget what this pattern is called, but it's one way of getting modifiable sub-behavior when there's an overall algorithm that stays fixed. For example, if you were writing a generic pager, its print function might be: WritePageNumber, WriteHeader, WriteNLines, WriteFooter, each of which could be modified, but the overall behavior is consistent.

Comment: It's called the "Template Method" design pattern.

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks guys. I had no idea it's legal to override private methods. I'll leave this up cause of the comments. :-)